# how to open .ics file in Android 2.1 version?

Tags: android

I just create a application that will download the ics files from the mail attachment.I use the Android 1.5 Emulator.It downloads the ics file and i can able to open that by using my application.But in the 2.1 simulator when i try to download the ics file The browser displays the ics file contents .I need to open that ics file by using my application only.

Answer (score 0):

Add the mime-type to your response header:

Content-Type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8

I get past this part, but the downloaded file doesn't open.